# docker-compse.yml spring boot mysql configuration

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have been trying to configure docker for my spring boot application with MySQL. But, I keep getting **communications link failure** error after running

> docker compose up

Here's a snapshot of the error

```
spring-batch_1  | 2019-11-14 06:23:43.713  INFO 1 --- [           main] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
spring-batch_1  | 2019-11-14 06:23:43.918 ERROR 1 --- [           main] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool 
initialization.
spring-batch_1  | 
spring-batch_1  | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link 
failure
spring-batch_1  | 
spring-batch_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The 
driver has not received any packets from the server.
spring-batch_1  |       at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[ . 
mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
spring-batch_1  |  at
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException
(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64 ) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
spring-batch_1  |       at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java- 
8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
spring-batch_1  |       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~ 
[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
spring-batch_1  |       at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java- 
8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
spring-batch_1  |       at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql- 
connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
spring-batch_1  |       at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP- 
3.4.1.jar!/:na]
spring-batch_1  |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~ 
[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
spring-batch_1  |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~ 
[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
spring-batch_1  |       at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP- 
3.4.1.jar!/:na]
spring-batch_1  |       at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) ~[HikariCP- 
3.4.1.jar!/:na]
spring-batch_1  |       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~ . 
[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
spring-batch_1  |       at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP- 
3.4.1.jar!/:na]
spring-batch_1  |       at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>) ~ . 
[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
spring-batch_1  |       at 
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core- 
5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
spring-batch_1  |       at 
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint
(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
spring-batch_1  |       at 
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed
(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
spring-batch_1  |       at 
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed
(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
spring-batch_1  |       at 
org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed
(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
```

Here's my **docker-compose.yml** file

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mysql:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 6033:3306
    expose:
      - 6033
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root@123
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=micro_services
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root@123
  spring-batch:
    restart: always
    image: ioesandeep/product-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
       SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:6033/micro_services
       SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
       SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root@123
       SPRING_JPA_DATABASE: mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

and here's my `dockerfile` which is used to build my **spring-batch image**

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} product.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/product.jar"]
```

I am using **dockerfile-maven-plugin** from **com.spotify** to build the image.
Here's my **application.properties** file for the spring boot and hibernate

```
spring.application.name=product
server.port=8082
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:6033/micro_services
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root@123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

`Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962`

`mysql  Ver 8.0.18 for macos10.14 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`

**Images**

`mysql                          latest                    c8ee894bd2bd        4 weeks ago`

`openjdk                        11-jdk                    a7e47afa852b        3 weeks ago`

I have tried a lot many configurations for the docker-compose file but every time I get the same error. I am not sure what am I missing in the configuration. I have been trying to get this up for over 2 days now. I would really appreciate a quick help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have your `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` as localhost (127.0.0.1):

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:6033/micro_services
```

Which as far as your `spring-batch` container is concerned is itself NOT the host machine so it will not be able to connect.

You will need to change it to reference the mysql container like:

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:6033/micro_services
```